# Что в привденном коде приводит к результату на картинке? (думал-думал, не догадался)

Tags: php, api, циклы, frontend, вывод

Вдруг сразу напротив даты затесался какой-то кусок непонятно от чего вместо названия учредителя. Дублируются доля и доля(руб)

```
<div class="item">
                                      <?php foreach ($value1[delete] as $key2 => $value2) {

                                              
                                        foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
                                            $change_t=$change_v = '';
                                         
                                            if(is_array($value3)) {
                                              //  echo "<br><br>";
                                               // print_r($value1[delete]);
                                               // echo "<br><br>";
                                               //   print_r($value1[add]);
                                                if($value1[delete][$key2][$key3][header]!=$value1[add][$key2][$key3][header]) {$change_t =  ' class="rename"';} 
                                                if($value1[delete][$key2][$key3][value]!=$value1[add][$key2][$key3][value]) {$change_v =  '<span'.' class="rename">';} 
                                              //  echo $value[$key1][delete][$key2][$key3][title].'!='.$value[$key1][add][$key2][$key3][title];
                                       echo '<p>'; if($value3[header]!='Должность:' && $value3[header]) {echo '<span'.$change_t.'>'; echo Users::DemoHide($value3[header],$demo , 5) ;  echo '</span>';}    
                                            echo $change_v.Users::DemoHide($value3[value],$demo , 3 );
                                            if($value1[delete][$key2][$key3][value]!=$value1[add][$key2][$key3][value]) { echo '</span>'; }
                                     if($key=='Руководитель' && !$value3[header])    {   echo '<span class="icon-name"></span>'; }
                                            echo '</p>'; 
                                         
                                          } }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо это не в приведенном коде, и не совсем понятно на картинке что именно не так, лучше выделить цветом.

Comment: Абсолютно нечитаемый код, какое-то нагромождение квадратных скобок.

Comment: Плюс названия переменных чудесные. `foreach($value as ` - как догадаться, что там перебирается? Легче удалить и написать заново, чем разбираться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном коде приводит к результату бардак.

Начнем с того что если у тебя в foreach есть еще один foreach, то уже что то пошло не так. И почитайте про PSR пару статей пж.